# Realloc() not changing memory address of already allocated memory?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void f(int **p) {
    printf("*p: %ptr\n", *p);

    *p = realloc(*p, 6*sizeof(int));

    printf("*p: %ptr\n", *p);
}


int main() {
    int *a = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
    printf("a before f(): %ptr", a);

    f(&a);
    printf("new a address after f(): %ptr\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, all the memory addresses are the same. Am I wrong to think that after the `realloc()` function is called on the address it should return a new memory address?

Comment: It can, but doesn't have to.  If there is enough consecutive space with the current address, why copy all that data to a new location?

Comment: Your call `int *a = malloc(3*sizeof(int));` would have allocated memory in whatever minimum block size your implementation uses. It is likely that is well above 12 bytes.

Comment: Why dou you have a blank line between each and every line in your code? It doesn't make it more readable.

Comment: OT: Using `%p` instead of `%ptr` just does it. You should though pass only a `void`- (or `char`-) pointer to the conversion specifier `%p`.

Answer (score 7):

Well it is correct behavior. (not violating any rules).

From [**standard**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5p1)

> The `realloc` function returns a pointer to the new object (which **may**
>   have the same value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer
>   if the new object could not be allocated.

Note the *may* that is highlighted in the above section. Yes it may return the same value as old one - it neither says it would be always new address or old one.

Just use them correctly. The thing is it will be expanded or shrinked as you requested in the second paaremeter of the `realloc`.

But your way of using `malloc` and `realloc` is **wrong**.

```
int *t = realloc(*p, 6*sizeof(int));
if(NULL == t){ /* Failure */
    perror("realloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
*p = t;
```

Same goes with the `malloc` too. ( Mentioned this because this may save you from many unwanted erroneous sitautions).

<sub>free the dynamically allocated memory when you are done working with it.</sub>

Comment: Awesome. I appreciate the fast response.

Answer (score 5):

> after the realloc() function is called on a it should change the memory address?

Not necessarily. The only requirement about its behaviour is to return a valid pointer if the operation succeeds and a null pointer otherwise.

The strategy it uses to accomplish this goal (to try to extend the block if possible or to move the data to a different block) is an implementation detail and it's subject to change any time without notice.